# A way to emit items after sourceObservable completed

Tags: rx-java2

Is there a way to wrap `Observable` in a way that chain will switch to another `Observable`, the way it works with `Maybe.switchIfEmpty(anotherMaybe)`, but something like

```
sourceObservable
.switchOnComplete(anotherObservable)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found that Observable.concatWith() is exactly what I needed.